# EXIM4: Signing Emails with DKIM

Tags: exim, dkim, txt-record

I really am banging my head against the wall with this one. I have tried for serveral days to get dkim signing to work on outbound emails from a server running on Debian 12, exim4 version 4.96, but to no avail. I don't even get DKIM error messages, just nothing.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Created a new public-private rsa pair in `/etc/exim4/dkim` (let's call them `domain-private.pem` and `domain-public.pem`)
2. Updated `/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp` to include the following:

```
remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp
  dkim_canon = relaxed
  dkim_domain = <domain name>
  dkim_private_key = /etc/exim4/dkim/domain-private.pem
  dkim_selector = apollo
```

3. Added a TXT record to my DNS provider (I won't add more details here for now as I don't think this is the relevant part).
4. Run `update-exim4.conf` and restarted the service.

When I try and send an email using exim however, there is no exim signing, no error, nothing. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting DKIM headers added to the emails you send?

Comment: @Jasen No, I'm not at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key file `/etc/exim4/dkim/domain-private.pem`
must be readable by the account exim runs external deliveries as `Debian-exim`

also be sure that you are editing the correct configuration (either split or combined)

Comment: The keys are both owned by `Debian-exim`. I'm pretty sure that exim was preinstalled on the server -- how can I tell if it's set up with split or combined configuration? I would have guessed the former since there are lots of sub-files in the `/etc/exim4/conf.d` folders

Comment: split or combined is a setting  (dc_use_split_config)  in `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf`  (managed by debconf)  presence of files is not indicative.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thank you @Jasen!!